# Mongodb fulltext search multiple phrases

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

As per documentation, if I want to search a phrase with `$text` I need to include the phrase in escaped quotations, but it will perform an `AND` operation, but how can I do an `OR` operation with multiple phrases

like

`"\"printer ink\" \"pen ink\" "`

should translate to `"printer ink" OR "pen ink"`